# getting data from database to html table using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

i want to fetch data from database and insert it in my html table here is my code i dont know where is my misatake:

```
    <div class="ibox-content">
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "sehnoqta_userbmc";
    $password = "u?gQ=uS%t;a?";
    $dbname = "sehnoqta_bmc";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $sql = "SELECT name, lastname, phone FROM regis";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $conn->close();
    ?>
            <table dir="rtl" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example" >
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Acc Type</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             echo
              "<tr><td>" . $row["name"]. "</td>
              <td>" . $row["lastname"]. "</td>
              <td>" . $row["phone"]. "</td></tr>";
              <td>0795934799</td>
              <td class="center">demo@demo.com</td>
              <td>Admin</td>
         }
         echo "</table>";
    } 
        ?>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
```

data i fetch from database shows out of table. 
sorry for bad English :)

Comment: just remove this two lines `0795934799` and `demo@demo.co` with ` $row["thatcolumnname"]`

Comment: 1) Remove `echo "</table>";`, you already have one outside of `if` block. 2) Remove `</tr>` from `"</td></tr>";` and put it at the end of table cell. 3) You're outputting HTML inside PHP in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Theres just a Syntax error in your while loop. You need to print everything inside the echo command. As you can see in yours, you have `echo(...);` followed by some HTML still inside the php. So you should correct it by changing it to the following.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo
          "<tr><td>" . $row["name"]. "</td>
          <td>" . $row["lastname"]. "</td>
          <td>" . $row["phone"]. "</td></tr>
          <td>0795934799</td>
          <td class=\"center\">demo@demo.com</td>
          <td>Admin</td>";
     }
```

A good resource that you can use is [phpchecker.com](http://www.phpcodechecker.com) that checks your code for errors

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that works...

```
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "sehnoqta_userbmc";
    $password = "u?gQ=uS%t;a?";
    $dbname = "sehnoqta_bmc";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $sql = "SELECT name, lastname, phone FROM regis";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $conn->close();
    ?>
            <table dir="rtl" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example" >
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Acc Type</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             echo
              "<tr><td>" . $row["name"]. "</td>
              <td>" . $row["lastname"]. "</td>
              <td>" . $row["phone"]. "</td>";
              "<td>0795934799</td>";
              "<td class='center'>demo@demo.com</td>";
              "<td>Admin</td></tr>";
         }
     echo "</table>";
 }
```

Hope this helps......

Comment: Thank you but it gives error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"<td>Admin</td></tr>"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /home/sehnoqta/public_html/test/MIS/user_lists.php on line 150 , line 150 is:  "<td>Admin</td></tr>";

Comment: now it gives me error on line 155: Error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/sehnoqta/public_html/test/MIS/user_lists.php on line 155 -  line 155: </table>

Answer (score 0):

```
         echo
          "<tr><td>" . $row["name"]. "</td>
          <td>" . $row["lastname"]. "</td>
          <td>" . $row["phone"]. "</td>
          <td>0795934799</td>
          <td class='center'>demo@demo.com</td>
          <td>Admin</td></tr>";
```

Comment: <tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Phone</th>
 <th>Email</th>
<th>Acc Type</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo
 "<tr><td>" . $row["name"]. "</td>
<td>" . $row["lastname"]. "</td>
<td>" . $row["phone"]. "</td>
 <td>0795934799</td>
<td class='center'>demo@demo.com</td>
<td>Admin</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
}
</tbody>
</table> //it gives error at line 155 which is </table>